PC suddenly not connecting to monitor through HDMI cable but HDMI cable and monitor works
I have a fairly new PC that I built (with new parts) about 2 months ago, and along with it I bought a brand new monitor and the monitor came with a brand new HDMI cable. I run plain old Windows 11. Nothing special.
It has been working fine for the time I've had it... until now. Just yesterday, I turn my computer on, and the light turned on, but the monitor said NO HDMI CONNECTION FOUND, indicating that it didn't register anything from my computer.
I thought at first it was either the monitor or HDMI cable malfunctioning, as this has happened before, but the monitor worked perfectly fine with my other PC. (Yes I have many more than one!)
I also tried the problem PC with many other screens and none worked.
Then I thought that maybe it was a problem with my graphics card, so I plugged the HDMI cable into my motherboard instead. But that didn't work either! So by now I was thinking that maybe my PC was internally broken, but after running a few tests with my ammeter, my motherboard seems to be supplying the right currents to every part. (Or at least every major part, such as the processors, disks, etc.)
At this point I was desperate, so I put in my Linux SSD from my other PC, to confirm it wasn't a software or driver issue, and it still didn't work.
At the moment I think I'll just take it to a real technician, but I was wondering if anyone here has anything, and I mean anything else to try?
In my desktop I have: an Intel Core i7-14700 desktop processor (UHD Graphics 770 integrated graphics), and a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 D. Also, I have completely taken out the graphics card, but using my CPU (with integrated graphics) still doesn't get it to work.

Is this device a desktop or laptop? What type of processor do you have? In order for the video port on the motherboard to be functional you need a CPU with an iGPU. You should [edit] your question and include all relevant information necessary to diagnose your issue.

@Ramhound I will.

And @Ramhound of course my CPU has integrated graphics- I have tried using it solely without the GPU at all and the display still doesn't work. I am quite advanced (for an amateur) at computers, and I just really don't see what the issue is.

When you press caps lock on your keyboard, does the corresponding LED light up? Have you tried taking out and re-inserting RAM? Can you ping your computer from another one (via Wi-Fi and/or Ethernet)? Is the computer even visible on ARP or DHCP tables or on your router?

You originally didn’t provide any specifics about your system and plenty of CPUs are sold without a iGPU and can be installed on a motherboard with a video port.

If there were any updates, it's quite possible that BIOS got one, too. Nowadays they install like any other Windows Update item. It may be possible the settings in BIOS got reset.
I had similar issue with my new PC several months back. I have a i5-13500 and RTX 4070, with 4 screens connected to GPU (2x DisplayPort, 1xHDMI and 1xUSB-C). It happened after I replaced old GPU with the RTX4070. The computer booted and showed no display on any of the monitors. I thought I did something wrong, but no.
Computer took nearly 15 minutes to start booting. Admittedly, I did some BIOS config prior to installing GPU, so maybe it was doing some internal adjustments or resolve some conflicts or something. I was powering down PC and looking for a hardware issue, but at some point, by chance, I got distracted and just left PC on and after some , but definitely longer than ever experienced time, it started booting. I am not around when it restarts after updates (it's office PC and it's set up for Update at 3AM), so I can't tell if it's still so slow to boot, but definitely had that issue before.
Edit:
I just remembered that my case involved upgrading GPU, doubling the system RAM (64GB -> 128 GB) and adding 2nd NVME drive, which may have had an impact on the PC and why it took so long to boot. I unplugged all external stuff before that, so all that was connected were monitors and wireless keyboard/mouse.

Thanks very much- what do you suggest I do?

@security_paranoid - put everything back as it was before fault, then power it up, make sure it is ON and not in any BIOS fault and - just like me - let it sit there for a while. If you assembled computers before, have confidence in your experience and assume it's all put back properly. I believe my PC needed at least 15 min to boot - that is windows logo and spinning dots to show up.


Hard reboot PC
If your monitor has other hdmi port, control the monitor menu(hdmi1, hdmi2)

I think it's not your hardware problem, Windows 11 have many bugs yet.

Did you remove Windows disk when you mounted Linux disk? If it didn't work with Linux too, it may be a problem with UEFI/BIOS settings.

Thanks for the answer- in my question I said that yes, it didn’t work with Linux either. But probably internal parts, I am thinking.
